Should I bring a gift for my supervisor based in a university in Central Europe?
I am an incoming STEM PHD student in a Central European university. I am from South Asia.
I got admission to PhD program in Central Europe. My new supervisor really encouraged me to apply to do a PhD with him. I have had good communication with him over e-mails and 2 times over Zoom. He told me what to study until I am granted a visa to go to Europe. He also very passionately told me about the research area. I am positive that we will get along well.
Should I bring a gift to him from my culture (sweets, clothes or something else) to say thank you for really encouraging me to apply for PhD and guiding me? Since I am coming from far away he might expect me to bring me something from my culture. Or this is considered bad manners in Central Europe?
Should I purchase something to gift him or not?

Avoid any gifts until you have a strong grip on the local culture. You are never doing anything wrong showing up motivated and empty-handed.

Where specifically?  Switzerland, Germany, Hungary, and Serbia have big cultural differences in etiquette. // Relatedly, it would be helpful if answerers could include which countries they’re speaking mainly from experience of.

As a side note, many European counties have restrictions on what can be brought in, particularly anything containing meat, dairy or raw fruit\vegetables. Anything edible should be in air tight packaging, and have the ingredients written on the side in the language for that country, or if not possible then at least in English. Alcohol may also be subject to heavy taxation. culturally relevant crafted goods may be easiest. Such as decorations associated with a local festival.

@xLeitix "until you have a strong grip on the local culture" - this sentence alone is missing from many responses below. I recommend making it into a response.

The regulations in our place are very strict. While there is a perfectly reasonable acceptance threshold before it needs to be returned or donated, all gifts, no matter how small, are to be reported. I therefore refuse categorically all gifts, as I really do not feel like filling 15-20 minutes of forms about value, origin, reason etc. and submitting them for each trinket, as well-intentioned as it was. To me, a gift is a punishment, not a pleasure. I can only highlight @xLeitix first-rate comment: the greatest gift you can bring to a supervisor is motivation.

Which country do you go to?

@CaptainEmacs Very sorry, due to my own privacy I can't be that precise.

@DVI Fair enough, I understand. It makes it harder to answer, but I guess then the fuzzyness of the responses comes with the territory.

PhD students giving gifts to their supervisors is not a part of (central) European academic culture. Thus, there should be no expectation that you bring anything.
Giving a gift with substantial monetary value (eg > €20) falls under anti-bribery regulations, and your supervisor would be obligated to reject and/or report the gift.

I agree with @Arno and @Marianne013's answers, but - if you're joining a research team, you could consider some kind of a mass token-gift. For example: Some confection/candy from your country which has many pieces, and then when you first arrive, you can bring that as a gift to the group, so that each person has one or two pieces. You could on that occasion offer your new supervisor the first piece, and thank them personally. That way, you're expressing the sentiment you want, but it's not a gift of any significant value, and there is no chance of perceived impropriety.
... of course that suggestion doesn't really work if it's, say, just the supervisor and another supervisee you rarely even see.

This. Bringing any kind of local food/candy/tea/coffee to the department/lab (as opposed to gifting them to a specific person) is always appreciated and avoids any kind of awkwardness that is associated with giving gifts to your supervisor.

In Germany, bringing along some food and/or drinks during your first or second week, and having a small gathering with the entire group, is so common, that there even is a word for this: "Einstand". (Typically not on your first day, if you don't know how many people to expect.) Not sure about other countries, though.

The short answer is no, you shouldn't.
The slightly longer answer is that it is not uncommon for students to bring their supervisors token gifts (e.g. tea, sweets etc) from their home countries at the end of their course/degree/studies. At this point they usually a) know their supervisor well enough to know how such a gift would be received and b) it cannot be mistaken by either the supervisor or university administration as an attempt at bribery.

Personal gifts have different meanings in different cultures.
In Central Europe, you are not expected to give gifts in this situation. First, to be acceptable, the value of a gift in Central Europe needs to be small and clearly symbolic. Otherwise it would fall under bribery regulations and put the receiver into an embarrassing situation. Even without fear of regulations, giving a gift creates a difficult situation for the recipient. So, giving a gift to a superior or supervisor is just not a good idea.
Second, it is much more common to do something for your new colleagues. If you'd be working in construction, you might be expected to pay for a round of beer for new colleagues, but in Academia, this is not customary at all. So, bringing a box of candy or tea or coffee from your home country, as long as the value is small, for the socializing events that are common (e.g. 10 am coffee, afternoon coffee) is acceptable but not expected. It will make everyone else uncomfortable because they now have to do the same thing, or maybe not, or maybe yes. So, you'd have to make up a story, like your Grandma insisted or you do not like tea and someone gave it to you, ...
Since you have to pack and since the only way for a mitbringsel to be acceptable is something small and personal, that you can describe as purely coincidental, I would not bother.
Once you have established relationships, things are slightly different. For example, if you have a home visit, you can ask whether you should bring something and your professor can pay for it. It is more acceptable but still not appropriate for the superior in the relationship to give a token gift to the inferior.
People in Academia are used to traveling and know about cultural differences. So, if you were to give a gift, they can probably handle it and will not hold it against you. Usually, you will find colleagues that are willing to help you navigate culture. Once you arrived, ask them what the customs are. In Central Europe, there is a sense of solidarity among co-workers that need to stick together.

"So, you'd have to make up a story, like your Grandma insisted or you do not like tea and someone gave it to you, ..." This seems like a stretch from my Czech perspective.

That's because I am German and no longer living in Germany.

Do not bring it to your supervisor specifically, but to the research group. I have visited and stayed with several research groups during the past few years and I always brought sweets (pre-packaged, not home-made) from my home or residential country. They were always devoured pretty quickly by grateful students (and the PI). A good way to start in a new place ;)
Good luck with your new position!

look up what you can acutally take with you... don't make a big fuss about it.
just bring something small, like 2 bars of chocolate and a big bag of candy that you liked as a kid or something.
Bring something that you enjoy very much and that you want to share.
Something of importance to you our your culture... as a gesture. Whatever you think fits best... maybe something historical, something from your research field, a funny qirk...

What are you basing this on?

being german, having been in academia (media and arts mainly), knowing quirky nerds, knowing german law and habits... beeing a basic human being.. what else? :)

Contrary to a lot of the answers above, I would advise against food gifts (including sweets, snacks, food speciaties, etc.) for dietary restrictions. If there are any food poisoning, you're liable. Expensive gifts could be turned down because the advisor might want to avoid conflict of interest (i.e. other people thinking that you bribed the advisor). Gifts that are too personal might not be a good idea, because you just knew this advisor in a professional setting.
You can definitely write your advisor a thank you card though, and maybe a self-made card if you are good at arts and crafts. That would be very thoughtful without possibly violating anything, and your advisor will know your gratitude. This is my go-to gift when showing gratitude in professional relationships in academia.

"You can definitely write your advisor a thank you card though, and maybe a self-made card if you are good at arts and crafts." Very nice advice IMO!

So are you advising against giving food gifts in general, at any occasion? Seems an exaggeration.

@user1079505 Unless you are familiar with their dietary restrictions (i.e. have asked directly what they can or cannot eat), yes. I would want to avoid any awkwardness in case the advisor turns down the food or suffers from any food poisoning.
